# Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

I have a running cloud-based application that uses AWS Amplify, S3, SageMaker, Dynamodb, etc.  Every other time I go to make an update to my graphql schema, it results in the error "resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete".  Sometimes it takes hours to fix itself, and others it takes days.  The other solutions to this problem are removing authorization and reinstalling, or viewing the status reason in CloudFormation.  Unfortunately, I already have triggers set up for the project and removing the resource is not an efficient solution.  Also, the "status reason" is empty, so that is no help.

There needs to be a way to make multiple updates at once in graphql without it breaking the system.  I hope this reaches the right person because I do like the AWS resources, but this makes development very tedious for no reason.